# Ar.js not able to display glb model

Tags: gltf, ar.js

I am not able to display my glb for image tracking using ar.js
please check my web https://ignaciostellino.github.io./
I am able to recognize the image but not to display the 3D model. I guess should be related with the scale and position but not able to figure out.
This is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@1c2407b26c61958baa93967b5412487cd94b290b/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>

<style>
  .arjs-loader {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .arjs-loader div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <!-- minimal loader shown until image descriptors are loaded -->
  <div class="arjs-loader">
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
  </div>
  <a-scene
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
    renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
    embedded
    arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled: false;"
  >
    <!-- we use cors proxy to avoid cross-origin problems -->
    <!-- url="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/trex-image/trex" -->
    <a-nft
      type="nft"
      url="ignaciostellino.github.io/smoothie-peque/smoothie-peque"
      smooth="true"
      smoothCount="10"
      smoothTolerance=".01"
      smoothThreshold="5"
    >
    <!-- gltf-model="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/scene.gltf" -->
      <a-entity gltf-model="Water/out.glb" scale="5 5 5"
            position="50 150 0" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <a-animation attribute="rotation" to = "360 0 0" dur="3000" easing="linear" repeat="indefinite"> </a-animation>
      </a-entity>
    </a-nft>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is, perhaps your model is too small or too large. How can you be sure the marker is detected? Try using `<a-gltf-model>` instead of `<a-entity>`. You can also use our platform [echoAR](https://www.echoar.xyz) to upload your models and immediately get an AR.js experience link (learn how [here](https://docs.echoar.xyz/ar.js/deploy-experience)). You can compare your code with the auto-generated one or just use the ARjs link that you get.